# Why is my Button's text cut-off?

Tags: android

I got a normal button, but the text is cut-off. I don't know why it's happening.

Can anybody analyze why it happened?

Code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_project_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Default Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000" 
        android:shadowDx="1.5" 
        android:shadowDy="1.5" 
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        /></LinearLayout>
      <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:background="@drawable/whitebg"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
  android:orientation="vertical">

     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    >
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/project_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"   
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="3" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="5" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_project"
        android:layout_width="181dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Project Title"
        android:textColor="#0e3946"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_organization_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Organization Title"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="#20822c"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    >
     <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:button="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:text="als Favorit markieren"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

      <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/txt_amount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#0E3946"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text=" "
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />

      <Button
          android:layout_marginTop="3dp" 
          android:id="@+id/btn_sms_spenden"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Jetzt Spenden!"
          android:textSize="13sp"
          android:textColor="#0e3946"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          />
      </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Image:

[image: See the red circled area]

Comment: try adding padding to the button

Comment: So how did you determine how much padding to add? Not sure why below is the accepted answer. It doesn't tell you anything.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try adding padding to the button

> android:padding

Answer (score 1):

Problem may be with android:layout_weight you are using..Its mainly used for controll/distribute the space within the view.

Comment: possibly. since the LinearLayout parent of the button has android:layout_weight="5", maybe the button did not "wrap_content" as it should properly. I tried it on my graphical layout viewer and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to give answer,

1) as @Last Warrior said try that removing the margin

2) You have define the size of text to 13sp and I think there are no enough space for 13sp because of the layout below the button

3) you must have given some fixed size or Weight attribute to the Layout that containing the Button and all the upper layout of the XML so the space ends at Button and the text gets cut.

4) try giving size to wrap_content or fill_parent and if you used the weight then see that your size in dp/sp doesn't gets out of the bounds of weight.

Comment: you could have post your whole xml code using www.pastebin.com and give here link to that..so all can get what you are doing?

Comment: post your own ans with details..and accept your own..:) so other gets to know that problem is solved..and if anyone find same problem also gets help

Answer (score -1):

change the line

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="20dp" //or above to 20dp then check
```

in your xml from button section...

Comment: android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
shouldn't affect the positioning of the text inside.

Comment: get back the removed line and give android:layout_height="20dp"

Comment: with android:layout_height="20dp" or more, the button is cut off. I've removed the weight as well but it doesnt seem to work