# How can avoid text from being cut off on a button?

Tags: android, button

I am customizing a button in Android changing its background (using a 9patch png file) and changing its font typeface. I put the button in a `RelativeLayout` since I need precise positioning and dimensioning of this item in a custom layout. I am doing all this programmatically (from creation to setting and display).

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242005/why-is-my-buttons-text-cut-off) with the same problem, but the solution will not work for me. I used

```
continueBtn.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

but the graphical output remains the same. More than half the text is cut off in the view.

An excerpt of the code I am using is the following:

```
Button continueBtn = new Button(getContext());
p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, 45);
p.addRule(CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

continueBtn.setLayoutParams(p);
continueBtn.setTypeface(...);
continueBtn.setTextSize(14);
outerLayout.addView(continueBtn);
continueBtn.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

No matter where I put the `setPadding` method call, things won't change.
What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: You probably want to add padding to your LayoutParams before setting them for the button? Why will the padding solution "not work for [you]"?

Comment: You used .setPadding with just 0 value? Have you tried padding without RelativeLayout?

Comment: @matt5784 I cannot add padding to `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, since I cannot see any suitable APIs. @Ali I used `.setPadding` with a couple of different values, but nothing changed.

Comment: Does the `setGravity` method do anything? Also, might try `setTextSize` to see if making it smaller helps... actually, have you tried changing the `p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, 45);` line to like 50 or 55 instead of  45?

Comment: If I increase the size of the button everything works correctly, since increasing the height of it reduces the amount of text cut off. But, as I said in another comment, there's plenty of space in the area occupied by the button to completely display the text, so I don't know why I have to increase its size. And, by the way, I cannot do it because of layout constraints.

Comment: Don't know why, but I've been working on another part of the project, now I came back to this and the problem has disappeared. Probably it would have been sufficient doing a full clean of the project?

Answer (score -1):

You are setting a constant height for the button of 45 (pixels, I guess). However, apparently the text you are trying to put in it is taller than the amount of space android will let you use. Make your button taller (by changing the LayoutParams) and it will fit without cutting off. Alternately, use a smaller text size so the text will be shorter and fit.

Comment: This is exactly what I cannot do. By the way, there's plenty of space in the area occupied by the button to completely display the text, but apparently it doesn't show up correctly.

Comment: P.S. if your layout is that precisely calibrated, and is using pixels (instead of dp) it is only going to work on the one screen resolution you are testing on... so your layout won't be perfect anyways (except on your device).

Comment: Obviously I will change all dimensions to `dp`, since I will test it on 6-7 different devices :)

Comment: You missed my earlier comment... `Post a screenshot, please. – matt5784 2 hours ago`  You also didn't address my suggestion about changing text size. IIRC, buttons have a small amount of innate padding so that the text sits inside the border a bit.